# Cytoscape link drop support

Tags: cytoscape.js

I am currently using Cystoscope java script library to build graph by drag and dropping an element(from component palette/panel) on the canvas div container using HTML events drop and drag over  along with edge-handles extension to make link between nodes manually.

## For more information

I have a floating panel which will list various types of components(of type say 'palette-node' div elements), using HTML5 drag and drop this component is dragged and dropped on canvas container div. By capturing drop event on target canvas container, I am creating new node(type canvas-node) in the canvas by calculating mouse co-ordinates. This works as expected and able to add as many number of nodes in the canvas by drag and drop event from floating  panel to cystoscope container element.

Now I am checking if there is a possibility to drop on link so that dropped will be inserted in between other two nodes which linked already. I could not find appropriate way to detect node(palette-node from floating panel) drop on cystoscope link object. Would you please provide any thoughts to resolve this?

I have tried listening drop event on link by drop, drop free events in cystoscope instance Cy, but it was not detected as I am dropping different type (div of palette-node from floating panel).

1. Listener declaration on cytoscape container div element

   ```
   this.containerElem.current.addEventListener("drop", this.dropHandler, false);
   this.containerElem.current.addEventListener("dragover", this.dragOverHandler, false);
   ```
2. Drop handler to add new node in the cytoscape graph

   ```
   dropHandler = (dropEvt) => {
       dropEvt.preventDefault();
       let eventSource = this._getDragEventSource(dropEvt);
       if (eventSource.type === "palette-node") {
         let compType = eventSource.data.type;
         let position = this.getPosition(dropEvt);
           nodeData = {
             type: compType,
             x: point.x,
             y: point.y
           };
          createDiagramNode(nodeData);

       }
       return false;
     }
   ```